# Enter date equilvalent to another row with BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the `first_open` users for the past 30 days. The query is working but will not work with my actual graphing JS because if a date has no `first_open` events, it will return nothing. I need to be able to get this query to work so that when there are no results on a date, it just returns that `datapoint_time` and 0 for the `datapoint_value`

My query:

```
WITH allTables AS (
  SELECT 
    user_dim.app_info.app_id as target,
    COUNT(event.name) as events, 
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY, 'UTC') as date
  FROM `table_one.*`
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(event_dim) as event
  WHERE event.name = 'first_open'
  GROUP BY date, target

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    user_dim.app_info.app_id as target,
    COUNT(event.name) as events, 
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY, 'UTC') as date
  FROM `table_two.*`
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(event_dim) as event
  WHERE event.name = 'first_open'
  GROUP BY date, target
) SELECT target as target, unix_seconds(date) as datapoint_time, events as datapoint_value FROM allTables 
WHERE
date >= TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Day, 'UTC'), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fill gaps in dates - you need to [generate all dates](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_date_array) in the time period of your interest - looks like it is last 30 days, so it can be like below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT datapoint
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), 
  CURRENT_DATE())
) AS datapoint
```

so now, you should use this in your query as in example below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH allTables AS (
  SELECT 
    user_dim.app_info.app_id AS target,
    COUNT(event.name) AS events, 
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY, 'UTC') AS date
  FROM `table_one.*`
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE event.name = 'first_open'
  GROUP BY date, target
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    user_dim.app_info.app_id AS target,
    COUNT(event.name) AS events, 
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY, 'UTC') AS date
  FROM `table_two.*`
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE event.name = 'first_open'
  GROUP BY date, target
) 
SELECT 
  IFNULL(target, '-') AS target, 
  UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(datapoint)) AS datapoint_time, 
  IFNULL(events, 0) AS datapoint_value 
FROM (
  SELECT datapoint
  FROM UNNEST(generate_date_array(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), CURRENT_DATE())) AS datapoint
)
LEFT JOIN allTables 
ON DATE(date) = datapoint
WHERE date>= TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Day, 'UTC'), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
ORDER BY dateASC
```

So, you take all the dates within the last 30 days and you left join to your initial sub-query. Please note: no changes in your initial subquery so I assume it really worked for you with the only exception of gaps in dates
Hope this helped

Comment: `Error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATE. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [31:4]`

Comment: The query seems to be working but it's not returning what I need it to. I probably explained it poorly in the original question but what I need is that for dates that do no have any events, I need the date and then 0 as a value for events.

Comment: that's exactly what is expected to be returned with query in my answer. so I think you should provide more specific example of what you see in output that is not how you expected and show how exactly you expected it to be

Comment: So basically what is happening is I'm passing the results of the query into D3.JS. For days that have no first_open event, I need the datapoint_value to be 0 and the date to be the actual date.

Comment: and that is exactly what my answer does!!! if you see opposite  - show exactly example of it! it is possible that something is mistyped or something else that ideally you should be able to troubleshoot as you given an idea. but if you cannot troubleshoot by yourself  - at least make sure you show clearly current issue. help us to help you :o)

Comment: just a sec - i think i see typo in my answer - give me a sec

Comment: fix is in line `UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(datapoint)) AS datapoint_time,`   - i forgot to change field `date` to `datapoint` . At the same time  - you should start  consuming help you are getting from SO people like me  - not just as one time help  - but as a learning. try to understand stuff, troubleshoot it , etc

Comment: I would also recommend to replace `UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(datapoint)) AS datapoint_time,` with `datapoint AS datapoint_time,`